# Come posso tradurre questo uso figurato dello spagnolo "farsa" ("sham" in inglese)?

Tags: word-choice, translation

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/farsa) ho trovato che "farsa" si usa oggi per indicare in modo spregiativo

> qualunque commedia, teatrale o cinematografica che, priva di valore artistico, si proponga il solo scopo di eccitare il facile riso di spettatori non raffinati

e anche in senso figurato per

> Cosa non seria, buffonata

La parola "farsa" esiste anche in castigliano e in catalano e si può usare per riferirsi a un certo tipo di spettacolo teatrale satirico (senza intenzionalità spregiativa), ma è vero che nell'attualità si usa di più in modo spregiativo con un senso simile alla prima definizione del Treccani qui riportata.

Tuttavia, come si può vedere nell'accezione numero 2 del [*Diccionario de la lengua española*](https://dle.rae.es/farsa?m=form) della Real Academia Española, in spagnolo e anche in catalano si usa
molto questo vocabolo in senso figurato per definire un'azione fatta per fingere o apparire, cioè, con una finalità ingannevole, anche qui con una forte connotazione spregiativa e spesso di giudizio di ipocresia.

Per esempio, qualcuno fa di nascosto una determinata azione. Altre persone se n'accorgono, ma non hanno idea su chi sia l'autore o l'autrice di questi fatti. Allora (o persino prima che se ne renda conto nessuno)
il vero autore scrive qualcosa giudicando come assolutamente riprovevoli questi fatti, mostrando una grande indignazione per quello accaduto e augurandosi che l'autore si faccia manifesto ben presto e lo fa semplicemente per apparire di avere delle convinzioni completamente diverse da quelle che ha veramente (non per paura di essere punito per l'azione fatta perché non si tratta di un'azione che vada punita) e così guadagnarsi la simpatia di altre persone. In catalano o in castigliano questo
atteggiamento verrebbe qualificato come una "farsa".

Altri esempi potrebbero essere quando una persona finge di essere gravemente malata per non andare al lavoro o quando si fanno delle elezioni per simulare l'essere democratici, ma in realtà quelli che saranno
i vincitori di queste elezioni sono stati decisi precedentemente.

La mia domanda è: posso usare "farsa" in italiano con questo significato?

Il fatto che questa accezione non appaia esplicitamente sul Treccani mi fa sospettare che forse ci sia un termine o espressione migliore per riferisi a questo concetto. Se è così, me lo potreste indicare?

Per fare la domanda più concreta, in riferimento agli esempi precedenti, in spagnolo si potrebbe formulare una frase come

> Todo ha sido **una farsa**

che, tradotta in italiano, magari sarebbe

> Tutto è stato ________? _______.

Quale parola o espressione potrei usare in questa  frase come traduzione? E, se non si trattasse di una buona scelta per fare la traduzione, come potrei tradurre in italiano la frase che ho scritto in castigliano? (magari perdendo qualche sfumatura: so che le traduzioni "perfette" spesso non esistono).

---

#Aggiornamento:

Ecco un esempio tratto dal romanzo [*Conversación en La Catedral*](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=MSuzAAAAQBAJ&q=farsa#v=snippet&q=farsa&f=false) di Mario Vargas Llosa (grassetto mio):

> Los enemigos del régimen se estaban aprovechando de este pretexto para decir que las elecciones fueron **una farsa**.

Questo libro è stato tradotto in italiano col titolo [*Conversazione nella cattedrale*](https://www.lafeltrinelli.it/smartphone/libri/mario-vargas-llosa/conversazione-nella-cattedrale/9788817138383) da Enrico Cicogna (magari qualcuno riesce a trovare questa traduzione).

Inoltre, si è fatto la proposta di cercare di spiegare il significato in inglese in modo che si possa capire meglio. Credo che una buona traduzione di questo uso figurato di "farsa" sia l'inglese "sham", che, per esempio, sul [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sham) viene definito così:

> COUNTABLE NOUN <sub>[usually singular]</sub> 
> Something that is a **sham** is not real or is not really what it seems to be.
>
> [*disapproval*] 
> The government's promises were exposed as a hollow sham. 
> Many of the world's leaders have already denounced this election as a sham.
> ...sham marriages.

Anche il [dizionario Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sham#other-words) riporta

> *sham* applies to fraudulent imitation of a real thing or action

e dà questo esempio

> condemned the election as a *sham*

In questo modo, io tradurrei la frase di Vargas Llosa così:

> The enemies of the government were taking advantage of that pretext to say that the elections were **a sham**.

Come esprimireste "the elections were a sham" in italiano?

Comment: A orecchio, prima di verificare altre fonti (e per questo non è una risposta), direi che anche in italiano ci sia il senso di “un'azione fatta per fingere o apparire, cioè, con una finalità ingannevole”, ma con la connotazione pesantemente critica che sia appunto una buffonata, una presa in giro nei confronti di qualcuno. Un esempio tipico potrebbe essere un concorso pubblico di cui è già stato deciso in anticipo il vincitore; lo si potrebbe chiamare “farsa” in più di un senso: è una messinscena, non è serio, è una presa in giro nei confronti dei partecipanti più meritevoli, è una finta.

Comment: @DaG: Se non è chiedere troppo, potresti cercare di scrivere una risposta?

Comment: @DaG:  Forse l'italiano "farsa" è, per le ragioni che hai spiegato nel tuo commento, una buona scelta di traduzione dello spagnolo "farsa" o dell'inglese "sham" nei contesti spiegati nella domanda e dovresti scriverlo in una risposta: anche se si perdono sfumature, magari non si può trovare niente di meglio. Le proposte che appaiono adesso nelle risposte non sembrano buone.

Comment: @DaG: Cercando Vargas Llosa, sono riuscita a trovarne un'altro. In questa [tesi di dottorato](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11011206.pdf) (dottorato di ricerca in scienza della traduzione) si trova il testo originale di un capitolo del romanzo *Historia de Mayta* di Vargas Llosa e la traduzione fatta dalla autrice della tesi. Ecco un brano del testo: "Pero ¿y si esto que me ha contado es exageración, pura mentira? ¿No será todo una farsa premeditada para exculparse de un prontuario que lo avergüenza?".

Comment: @DaG: La traduzione: "Ma se quello che mi ha raccontato fosse un'esagerazione, una menzogna? Non sarà tutto una farsa 
premeditata per discolparsi di un passato di cui si vergogna?". Ho dato un'occhiata alla traduzione (non soltanto a questo brano) e mi sembra una buona traduzione. Questo ribadisce l'idea che appunto "farsa" sia una buona scelta e che potresti scriverlo come risposta. Puoi usare questo esempio, se vuoi. **Può anche usare questo, se lo considera utile, qualsiasi persona che voglia scrivere una risposta**.

Comment: Direi che, oltre che con "farsa" si può rendere anche con "pantomima". Personalmente, tenderei ad utilizzare più "farsa" per una situazione e "pantomima" per un comportamento.

Answer (score 2):

> La mia domanda è: posso usare "farsa" in italiano con questo significato?

Sì: usando "farsa" si aggiunge un giudizio negativo, simile per esempio a "buffonata".

Un termine più neutro è "messinscena", che indica appunto una scena, montata ad arte per mostrare qualcosa che, probabilmente, non è reale.

Allargando un poco il discorso, è possibile usare altre parole o perifrasi, come a esempio "fare un teatrino", "inscenare", "simulare"; per descrivere le elezioni fittizie riportate nella domanda, si potrebbe anche dire "elezioni finte" o "false elezioni".

Comment: Quello che trovo qui è che, io stessa, con l'aiuto di dizionari bilingui, avevo proposto in una risposta "messinscena" e "finta" come possibili traduzioni. Ma la risposta era stata giudicata come cattiva, cioè, è rimasta per due mesi con un bilancio negativo di voti, fino a quando io stessa decisi di cancellarla. Questo mi fa sospettare che neanche questa risposta  sia  buona.

Comment: @charo Se sei sicura che non sia una buona risposta metti il tuo downvote. Io però non la cancellerò, come facesti tu, perché sono più che sicuro che non sia sbagliata.

Comment: "Sospetto" non è lo stesso di "esserne sicura". Nessuno ti sta chiedendo di cancellare la risposta.

Comment: @charo, allora non capisco perché hai postato il primo messaggio. Una nota per sollevare dubbi nella mia testa? Una rivendicazione come "ero stata io a rispondere per prima"? Qual'è il significato? (quale con l'apostrofo, è intenzionale)

Answer (score 2):

Aggiungo una proposta di traduzione per

> Los enemigos del régimen se estaban aprovechando de este pretexto para decir que las elecciones fueron una farsa.

Con questa versione in italiano

> I nemici del regime si stavano avvantaggiando di questo pretesto per dire che si trattava di elezioni farsa.

**'Elezioni farsa'** è una traduzione sulla falsariga di espressioni che sono assolutamente comuni in italiano e nel linguaggio giornalistico in particolare, come "processo farsa" (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_farsa), ed esattamente con la stessa accezione riportata dalla RAE per lo spagnolo.

Qui alcuni esempi presi dai quotidiani:

> Maduro: se perdo, lascio. L'opposizione: elezioni farsa, non votate

https://www.avvenire.it/mondo/pagine/maduro-se-perdo-stavolta-me-ne-vado-guaid-boicotta-gi-deciso-il-risultato

> Lo votano due venezuelani su 10. Maduro festeggia le elezioni farsa

https://www.ilgiornale.it/news/politica/votano-due-venezuelani-su-10-maduro-festeggia-elezioni-farsa-1908257.html

> Algeria al voto tra proteste e boicottaggi: "Elezioni farsa"

https://www.repubblica.it/esteri/2019/12/12/news/algeria_al_voto_tra_proteste_e_boicottagi_elezioni_farsa_-243245452/

Answer (score 0):

Il termine *farsa*, come hai potuto leggere su Treccani, non ha connotazione tale da sottintendere una finalità ingannevole in senso spregiativo e sicuramente non si adatta alla situazione descritta nel tuo esempio.

Sicuramente è valido il suggerimento di @DaG per quanto riguarda il termine messinscena, ma io ritengo più appropriato il termine *dissimulazione*, derivato da [dissimulare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dissimulare/):

> **dissimulare** v. tr. [dal lat. *dissimulare*, propr. «render dissimile», comp. di *dis-* e *simulare*: v. simulare] (*io
>   dissìmulo*, ecc.). – Nascondere il proprio pensiero, o i sentimenti, i
>   propositi, ecc., in modo che altri non se ne accorga, spesso anzi
>   fingendo il contrario: *d. l’odio, il sospetto, la propria ansia; non
>   riuscii a d. la sorpresa, il disappunto; è molto abile nel d. le
>   proprie intenzioni;* anche assol.: *sa d. con molta arte.* Più
>   genericam. (ma solo in frasi di tono ricercato), nascondere, celare:
>   *non ti dissimulo che ho forti timori; cercai di dissimulargli la verità; non mi dissimulo le difficoltà dell’impresa.*

Ancora da Google:

> **dissimulazione** /dis·si·mu·la·zió·ne/
>   *sostantivo femminile* Comportamento, abituale o occasionale, diretto a celare il proprio pensiero o le proprie intenzioni o anche ad
>   allontanare da sé ogni sospetto.

C'è poi disponibile anche un'opera di Torquato Accetto intitolata *[Della dissimulazione onesta](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Della_dissimulazione_onesta/VIII._Che_cosa_%C3%A8_la_dissimulazione)* (1641) in cui viene descritto cos'è la dissimulazione:

> Da poi che ho conchiuso quanto conviene il dissimulare, dirò piú
>   distinto il suo significato. La dissimulazione è una industria di non
>   far veder le cose come sono. Si simula quello che non è, si dissimula
>   quello ch’è.

Anche Francesco di Bartolo da Buti, [commentando l'Inferno di Dante](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:Commedia_-_Inferno_(Buti).djvu/791) afferma:

> Simulazione è fingere vero quello che non è vero; dissimulazione è
>   negare quello che è vero; e quando la falsità si commette in fatti,
>   sempre queste due compagne sono con essa, et ancora à alcuna volta la
>   bugia per sua compagnia per lo spergiuro; ma quando si commette in
>   detti, che è bugia, possono essere insieme, et ancora può essere pur
>   l’una.

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone. Ho aggiunto un esempio in modo che si possa capire meglio a cosa mi riferisco. Scusa per non averlo fatto prima.

Comment: Ho corretto la risposta con una versione più adatta al contesto descritto nel tuo esempio.

Comment: Non so, @abarisone: "disimulación" esiste anche in spagnolo, ma non ha le stesse sfumature di significato: "farsa" ha una valenza spregiativa più forte di "disimulación". Ma forse non si può trovare niente di migliore. Sarebbe interessante trovare qualche testo letterario in cui si usi "farsa" con questa accezione del quale esista una buona traduzione in italiano.

Comment: @charo se cerchi una parola italiana, non pensare al significato che potrebbe avere per assonanza in spagnolo. Comunque ritengo che la parola più adatta sia *messinscena*.

Comment: @charo Io non capisco che cosa vuoi dire e come fai a sapere che "due utenti" hanno giudicato negativamente "messinscena"; però puoi chiedere a loro, sicuramente hanno idee migliori della mia. Su questa pagina https://educalingo.com/it/dic-it/farsa trovi sinonimi italiani anche fantasiosi, tra l'altro è un sito molto divertente, ed esiste anche la versione spagnola dove trovi sinonimi spagnoli.

Comment: Un esempio d'uso di 'farsa' con connotazioni negative è 'processo farsa' - https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_farsa